# MVC bootstrap popup opens multiple times

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

When I click in a button to open my popup form, it seems that it is being opened multiple times and in the browser console I get the error "(3) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null". What am I missing?

View containing the button:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/myscripts/JobOffers/JobOfferPopup.js"></script>

<div id="createJobOfferModal"></div>

<div id="jobOfferButtonsBar">
    <div style="float:left; padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;">
        <a class="btn btn-default" id="createJobOfferBtn" href="" data-url="@Url.Action("CreateOrUpdate", "JobOffers", new { jobOfferId = 0 })">Create</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Popup View Code:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg jobOfferForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createJobOffer" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="overflow-y:auto; max-height:70vh">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="createJobOfferLabel"> @Model.PopupTitle </h4>
            </div>
 <div class="modal-body" data-val="5">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client) </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Client" value="@Model.Client" style="width:25%;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveJobOfferBtn" data-url="@Url.Action("CreateOrUpdate", "JobOffers" )">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#createJobOfferBtn').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data("url"),
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("opened");
                $("#createJobOfferModal").html(result).find('.modal').modal({
                    show: true
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You should post your controller code as well

Comment: @What does your Ajax function do? Going by the name of the button it sounds like it should be posting a value rather than getting one.

Comment: The ajax function open's the popup. It is getting the popup html and put it inside the div #createJobOfferModal.

Comment: In your browser does it state where the error comes from? e.g. Javascript etc? I know in firefox using the developer tools will state which file the error occurred in.

Comment: Seems like your result injection in the success call fails. Are you sure the result has the html you expect?

Comment: Yes. But returns the html popup several times. If I click once, returns about 2 times the html. If I click again it returns 4, 5, 6 times, and so on.